# Battery capacity and parallel vs. series battery connections

Tags: power, batteries, inverter, energy, solar-energy

Say you have 4 200 Ah 12 V batteries connected in parallel, this as I’ve come to learn increases the amp-hour value and not the voltage, and say you have another system same as that but connected is series this time, this increases the voltage and not the amperage.

So for the first system you will be getting a total of 800 Ah at 12 V (I’m guessing this means you need a 12 V inverter right?)

And for the second one you will get 200 Ah at 48 V (and for this also I’m guessing you will need to have a 48 V inverter to run the batteries).

1. Now what is confusing me is why choose one over another?
2. If I have the first one the inverter is going to convert this to 220 V AC for me anyway and same for the second one, except for the second one as I’ve come to learn (btw I apologies and a newbie) you will be getting less battery runtime because the ah rating is lower but still that same 220 V AC power. I’ve been doing a lot of research and the terms themselves confused me a bit.
3. At the end I just need the basic knowledge of what works with what, why and how, a question of powering a house with 15 kW of load for 24 hours from just batteries? What would I need and what would be the best and most efficient way to acheive this and get the most out of the equipment and investment.
   Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Higher voltage means lower currents which means thinner wires. But higher voltage means more insulation, more safety questions, etc. With respect to batteries, you'd "prefer" to not stack them for higher voltage as putting them in series means the weakest cell among them is your limiting factor and will eventually fail you more quickly. But putting them in parallel also isn't so good for related reasons (weakest unit issue again.) Optimal would be one GIANT chemical cell. But that's not manageable, either. An octopus of cells tied through a controller is nice. But also not practical.

Comment: Higher voltage is better for conversion as overhead voltages make up a smaller % of the total and are therefore likely more efficient than reaching 220 VAC from 1.2 VDC would be. Cars (Toyota Prius Prime, Tesla, etc) use relatively higher voltages for efficiency reasons. But their battery systems are carefully crafted and tested. (Or so I hope, anyway.) So no particular bright line answer. What's your peak use likely to be and what do you expect as a "high average"? Are you thinking your average is 20 kW? That's almost 2000 megaJoules/day! A Tesla Powerwall cell would last about 30-40 minutes.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that in series the internal resistance of the cells is added together.  In parallel it is reduced, so if the efficiency of the inverters is the same then the parallel arrangement will be more efficient.  (obviously the efficiency of the inverters isn't the same though, so that is your first consideration).

Comment: Consider also 2S2P and a 24V inverter. Better than 12V  for I^2R losses. Not as good as 48V from that perspective but if one battery fails you can run from the other string (at half capacity). For (3) it's simple : 15kW for 24h = 15 * 24 kWh. Butyou probably don't need 15kW all the time.

Comment: Make sure you're not confusing amps with amphours!

Comment: @winny don't change the meaning of ops words. Capacity and amperage are not synonyms. If op is incorrect then they should be told the difference.

Comment: @Passerby Point taken.

Comment: You are confusing “amperage” with capacity. A = current. Ah = battery capacity. Please edit your post to correct this.

Comment: @winny point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why wire batteries in series vs parallel?

Series means higher voltage and lower current.  Lower current is good because it means *dramatically* thinner wire on long distances, especially at low voltage. 2x voltage means 1/2x current for the same useful power. 4x voltage means 1/4x current for same useful power.

However, higher voltage means danger. DC voltage starts being *rather feisty* as voltage gets higher, so switching it becomes much more complicated and dangerous. 24V is manageable but 48V starts to get interesting.  Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oaq2cvoPBRk) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThIbMnE71HU).   Once DC starts arcing, it cannot be reasoned with, it does not know pity or remorse or fear and absolutely will not stop, ever, unless killed at the source.

> I’ve come to learn you will be getting less battery runtime because the ah rating is lower but still that same 220 V AC power.

No, useful power is volts x amps.  If you double volts but halve amps, you have exactly the same useful power.  (except for voltage drop of course).

Another way of thinking of it, a battery is a box that can hold so many *watt-hours*.  So 12 volts x 200 amps = 2400 *watt-hours*.  It doesn't matter how you stack them, the boxes hold the same amount.  Four batteries is 9600 watt-hours, or 960 watts for 10 hours for instance.

...Except lead-acid batteries are rapidly degraded by deep cycling, so you'll destroy the batteries in a few dozen cycles if you dip them that deep.  A lead-acid should only be drawn down to about 70% charge (i.e. from 100% to 70%, so 30% useful) which means 2880 useful watt-hours in your pack.

> At the end I just need the basic knowledge of what works with what, why and how, a question of powering a house with 15 kW of load for 24 hours from just batteries?

15KW is 15,000 watts.  Multiply by 24 hours and you have 360,000 watt-hours. Obviously that plan isn't going to work.

Now if you're politically anti-solar and rootin' for Putin, congratulations. You have proven that solar is totally impractical!  Now you can shout down all those wrong people on the Internet *who claim to* be doing off-grid solar homes with great success. Fake news!

On the other hand if you're serious, let's figure out how they actually manage it. Because they actually do.

> What would I need and what would be the best and most efficient way to acheive this and get the most out of the equipment and investment.

Well.

Here's the trick.

Everybody wants a green thing that just "plugs in" where the black thing went.  The farmer wants to farm the same black way, but with *organic* fertilizers and *organic* pesticides and *organic* Roundup Ready seed.  What organic farming actually is, is doing a lot of things in a different way so that stuff is not required.

So it's the same thing here. One wants to keep the horribly insulated house, the COP 1.0 electric baseboard heaters, the same "2.0 SEER" 1-hose portable A/C units in every room, inefficient dryer that ejects conditioned air out of the house, etc. All that crud is built to be cheap and assume utility power is cheap. But batteries aren't, so you have to consider the cost of stupid numbers of batteries to power all that wasteful crud, vs. better stuff.

First,  you insulate the house for all it's worth, and if possible include passive solar design. Second, you use an efficient, 38 SEER heat pump for the air conditioning, increasing A/C efficiency *by a factor of nineteen*, that with the insulation means you are using 1/50 the electricity you used before for A/C.  Even though the insulation and heat pump is expensive, **it is cheaper than 50 times as much battery pack**.

You go through an efficientify every single appliance. Resistive electric dryer, ejecting air outside? Nope, heat pump dryer because that unit is cheaper than buying more batteries to run the ratty old dryer.  Refrigerator? Crunch the same math, maybe, maybe not.  Cable box that sits there sucking 50 watts 24x7?  Cut the cord.

Every single load gets rationalized... and suddenly you don't need 15,000 watts anymore, you need more like 500. And now battery is a player.

And then, forget the low-capacity short-life lead-acid batteries and go with electric vehicle batteries out of wrecks, such as a Tesla Model S blade, 5000 usable watt-hours for about $1000.

That is a bit of an up-front investment, but if you can't afford to replace an inefficient appliance, how do you expect to buy all the batteries you'd need to run it?

Comment: Very well detailed, thank you. After seeing those clips I don’t think I ever want to go beyond 12V. Also what you said about enffiecy really made sense, might put some of the cost there as we have alot of stuff pulling watts as it’s a family house, especially the AC’s. You also talked about voltage drops when increasing voltage, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Also would it be inefficient to use 12v in a high power & load system? I couldn’t even find an inverter that supported alot of load but that is 12v. Most big one’s I found are 48 or 120v.

Comment: @Nura 24V is safe enough. The voltage drop thing is that increasing the voltage *very greatly* improves the situation of moving the power from place to place (at the cost of needing top quality switch gear, not the stuff from that video LOL)....... As far as powering existing cheap appliances, that is not realistic for the reason I discuss in my last section.

Answer (score 3):

1. Converting 48V to 220V will require a quarter of the current of converting 12V to 220V.  That means you can get away with thinner wiring.
2. The total number of watt-hours in the batteries is the same whether you wire them in series or parallel.  Only looking at the amp hours is misleading.
3. No chance with the batteries you have.  15kW for 24 hours is 360 kilowatt hours.  800 amp hours at 12V is only 9.6 kilowatt hours.